# Duplicate Next & Previous button function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know what I need do to deduplicate the first slideshow container buttons. When I click next and previous button on first slideshow container this one haven't change, only the secound slideshow container changes.
You can run in your browser only changing pictures path.

**Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides1 {display:none}

body {
    background: #2c3338;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container1 {
  max-width: 350px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev1, .next1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next1 {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev1:hover, .next1:hover {
  background:#696969;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev1, .next1,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>

<style>
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides2 {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container2 {
  max-width: 350px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev2, .next2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next2 {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev2:hover, .next2:hover {
  background:#696969;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev2, .next2,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container1">

<div class="mySlides1 fade">
  <img src="img/thumb-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides1 fade">
  <img src="img/thumb-2.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides1 fade">
  <img src="img/thumb-3.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next1" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot1");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  }
</script>

</body>

<body>

<div class="slideshow-container2">

<div class="mySlides2 fade">
  <img src="img/thumb-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides2 fade">
  <img src="img/thumb-2.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides2 fade">
  <img src="img/thumb-3.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev2" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next2" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot2");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can change all the function and variable name of the second script:

```
slideIndex->slideIndex2
plusSlides -> plusSlides2
currentSlide -> currentSlide2
showSlides -> showSlides2
```

But you can try not to duplicate your script by pass a variable to the function:

```
plusSlides(1, 1) // mean next picture in slide 1
plusSlides(1, 1) // mean next picture in slide 1
plusSlides(2, -1) // mean previous picture in slide 2
plusSlides(2, -1) // mean previous picture in slide 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS functions and variables are duplicated (it will always react in a weird way). You should change names of them or refactor them to use the same functions for both slideshows.